# How do I calculate the length of return function?

Tags: javascript

```
for (i=0; i <2; i++) { 
function drinks () { 
    prompt("Please enter how many drinks you had drank.");
    var dNum = return "You had drank" + " " + drinks + "!";
}
}
if (dNum.length === 2) {
console.log("You are the lord of drinks!");
}
```

I'm just a newbie for Javascript. The code I've shown has many syntax errors, But I'm making an example for you to understand more directly. Hope you know what I meant ;) If not, Please ask.

Comment: It should be `var dNum = prompt("Please enter [...]");`, take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Comment: What are you actually trying to calculate the length of. Currently, you're testing for the length of the returned string, not the number of drinks, I'm assuming you want the number of drinks?

Comment: @DarkHippo Yes, I want to return the "You had drank" + " " + drinks + "!" and calculate how many returns are there. So I used a loop, but it seems quite incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the for-loop,

```
function drinks () { 
   var dNum = prompt("Please enter how many drinks you had drank.");
   return dNum;
}

if (drinks() == 2) {
   alert("You are the lord of drinks!");
}
```

You're right, you have a lot of errors in your code